# How to bake animation of non-transformation properties with curve-modifiers applied?

Tags: animation, baking, graph-editor, fcurves, curve-modifier

I have a point light source whose power has been animated with a noise curve-modifier to have a flickering effect. I want to cycle its animation over 12 frames. For transformation properties like location, rotation and scale, I can convert the modifier to keyframes by baking the animation via Object>Animation>Bake Action, and then cleaning up the remaining frames and adding a cycle modifier. How do I approach cycling the animation for the Power property of the light? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to get a keyframe animation from the *Noise* modifier is a bit confusing in Blender. It goes over baking and un-baking the curve. Usually, baking a curve removes keyframes to make the curve permanent, i.e. unalterable by keyframes. So baking the modifier curve gnerates no keyframes either. But now you can un-bake the curve to get keyframes. Here I'll show it step by step, these instructions work for other curve modifiers as well:

1. In the *Graph Editor*, select the curve with the *Noise* modifier and choose *Key > Bake Curve* from the menu or use the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. The result will be the curve in the frame range which is set as start and end for the animation, so e.g. frames 1-250.

[image: bake curve]

2. At first this might look incorrect, since the curve probably changes its appearance - that's because you now have the modifier on top of the baked curve. You can now delete the modifier.

[image: baked curve with modifier on top]

3. After you removed the modifier, the noise will look just like before the baking, but notice that it's only between the first and last frame. If you just want a smaller part of the curve, just set start and end frame accordingly before baking.

[image: baked curve without keyframes]

4. Since a baked curve has no keyframes, you now have to choose *Key > Un-Bake Curve* from the menu and already you have converted the *Noise* modifier into keyframes which you can edit like any other keyframe animation.

[image: un-baking the curve]

5. The resulting keyframed noise animation, now you can use a *Cycles* modifier or other things like tweaking the keyframes for smooth transition etc. to make it looping:

[image: keyframed noise]

Comment: Hey! That worked perfectly. thank you!

Comment: I did the same and have the keyframes in the graph editor, but I can't seem to find a channel for "Power" or its keyframes in the action editor. As a result, once I pushed down the action, I can't edit it again.

Comment: @jais Hmmm... I never use the _Action Editor_, not sure what's going on there.